# How to build an admin with multi categories in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'd like to build an administration page for my website, where I could use multiple checkboxes to store / updates many categories for a single post.
So I've created three tables:

```
POST Table (id (index, auto-increment, not null), subject, content)

CATEGORIES Table (id (index, auto-increment, not null), name)

POST_CATEGORIES Table (id (index, auto-increment, not null), id_cat (foreign key to CATEGORIES.id), id_post (foreign key to POST.id))
```

(This last table is building relations between the posts and its categories.)

So I'm trying to list the categories with multiple checkboxes. I'm doing this query, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
$select = $db->query('SELECT categories.id, categories.name, post_categories.id_cat AS fk_cat, post_categories.id_post AS fk_post, post.id AS post_id
  FROM `categories` 
    LEFT JOIN post_categories
       ON categories.id = id_cat
     LEFT JOIN posts
       ON post.id = id_post');
```

Result is i have a list of categories, but each category name is repeated depending on the number of posts having this category (e.g : if post 1 and post 2 have both category 1, category 1 will appear 2 times in my list).

**EDIT :**
Thanks for the replies, here is a sqlfiddle to see what's happening...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c304/1

(I'm trying to display a list of categories. I won't select * from categories table because in a next step, i'd like the right categories to be checked when i edit a post.)

Comment: A good way to ask these sorts of questions is to prepare a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so readers can see what the problem is (whilst also adding the detail into the question, as you have done). Being able to visualise the issue is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
              , c.name
              , p.id post_id
           FROM categories c
           LEFT 
           JOIN post_categories pc
             ON c.id = pc.id_cat
           LEFT 
           JOIN posts p
             ON p.id = pc.id_post
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it gives the same issues : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c304/4

Answer (score 0):

If i use `GROUP BY categories.id`, i don't have doubles anymore...

But it only keeps the first post which is "tagged" with the current category. I need to keep all those informations.

Maybe i should filter by a php query? Something like if count(category.id > 1) then only display the one where post_id = current post edit? (sorry if it's not clear, i feel a bit confuses :( )